Send Telegram Notification on New Order with order and order items details
I want to send a telegram notification to my group when a new order is received on my store.
I use the following code I've found in another thread:
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'telegram_notification',  1, 1  );
function telegram_notification( $order_id ) {

            $order     = wc_get_order( $order_id );


            $text = "*" . __( 'New Order') . "*\n\n";
            $text .= __( 'Order number') . ': ' . $order_id . "\n";
            $text .= __( 'Status') . ': ' . wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) . "\n";
            $text .= __( 'Date') . ': ' . $order->get_date_modified() . "\n";
            $text .= __( 'Email') . ': ' . $order->get_billing_email() . "\n";
            $text .= __( 'Total price') . ': ' . $order->get_total() . "\n";
            $text .= __( 'Payment method') . ': ' . $order->get_payment_method_title() . "\n";
            $xsl = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot12345:xxxxx-zzzzz/sendMessage?parse_mode=html&chat_id=-1234567890&text=" . $text);
}

I want to also send the product names and SKU, but I can't seem to figure it out. The original poster also had this problem.
Here's the question thread: WooCommerce notification with Telegram
Thank you in advanced for your time.
Tried various methods but none seem to print the products and products info.

What's the actual issue here? The part of sending the message through Telegram or the fact  that you can't echo/print the product names?

@DarkBee The Telegram part work, however it doesn't send the product info (name, sku etc).

Don't you think the title and the contents of your question is misleading then? Why not revise the title to the actual problem?

You just need to loop through order items, to add product(s) name(s) and SKU(s), like:
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'send_order_to_api', 10, 2 );
function send_order_to_api( $order_id, $order ){
    if ( ! is_a('WC_Order', $order) ) {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    }

    $text  = "*" . esc_html__('New Order') . "*\n\n";
    $text .= esc_html__('Order number') . ': ' . $order->get_order_number() . "\n";
    $text .= esc_html__('Status') . ': ' . wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) . "\n";
    $text .= esc_html__('Date') . ': ' . $order->get_date_modified() . "\n";
    $text .= esc_html__('Email') . ': ' . $order->get_billing_email() . "\n";
    $text .= esc_html__('Total price') . ': ' . $order->get_total() . "\n";
    $text .= esc_html__('Payment method') . ': ' . $order->get_payment_method_title() . "\n";

    // Loop through order line items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $text   .= esc_html__('Item') . ': ' . $product->get_name() . ' (' . $product->get_sku() . ')'. "\n";
    }

    $xsl = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot12345:xxxxx-zzzzz/sendMessage?parse_mode=html&chat_id=-1234567890&text=" . $text);
}

It should work.

Related:

How to get WooCommerce order details
Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3


Thanks for the reply. It should, but it doesn't. After "Payment method", nothing else is sent to Telegram.
"[...] Total price: 83.99_Payment method: Numerar la livrare_"
Tried on 2 different Woocommerce instances.

@AlexandruT. I tested my code with a new order using error_log() instead of sending a Telegram notification. I get everything, even order items data (product name and sku) on the error log. So my code works, see it on this screenshot, so there is nothing else that I can do… Maybe there is a limitation of length with Telegram notifications sent via their API.

Thanks! I will try it too. Much appreciated.
